# 2048-bit vs. 4096-bit TLS cert performance difference?

Tags: tls, performance

Is there any difference in performance between using, say, a 2048-bit TLS cert compared to a 4096-bit one? If so, how much difference in performance could there be? If not, why use 2040- over 4096-bit TLS certs?

Comment: Should be slower by a factor 6 or so.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Why factor of ~6?

Comment: It is slower at asymmetric not symmetric:  It is only slower at setting up the connection, not the ongoing data.  If you are using very short connections, then it will make a difference, if this is for a "lot" of data, like a VPN or a video stream, then it will make little to no measurable difference.

Comment: @MikeP Yeah, I'm assuming the bulk cipher etc. are all the same, the only difference being the cert's key length, so I suppose I could be more precise and asking exactly how much difference in handshaking time etc. there'd be.

Comment: @Geremia It's not so much time as it is processing power.  A longer key will put a lower limit on the amount of connections/second you can negotiate.  If you have low connection requirements, it won't matter.